# RegEx for replacing part of a string including single quotes (')

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to replace a portion of a text that is between apostrophes, not all, just a part.
For example, I need to replace the characters /* and */ that are only within text between quotes by null text but not outside them.

**My input text, for example:**

```
A = 'THIS IS AN ALPHABETIC /* CONSTANT' || WS_CON1 /* */ || 'TEST STRING */';
```

**Expected output:**

```
A = 'THIS IS AN ALPHABETIC  CONSTANT' || WS_CON1 /* */ || 'TEST STRING ';
```

I extracted the texts in quotes but I do not know how to replace the /* and */ with null text.

```
Sub ReplaceWithRegex()
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim regEx As Variant
    Dim strtxt As String

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    strtxt = "A = 'THIS IS AN ALPHABETIC /* CONSTANT' || WS_CON1 /* */ || ' TEST STRING */';"
    strPattern = "\'([^\']*)\'"
    strReplace = ""

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strtxt) Then
        Debug.Print regEx.Replace(strtxt, strReplace)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not matched")
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously, this replace all text between quotes to null string.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly the logic behind your replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another VBA method using Regular Expressions.

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Function reReplaceComment(S As String) As String
  Dim RE As RegExp
  Dim I As Long, J As Long

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "('[^']*?)(?:(?:/\*)|(?:\*/))([^']*?')"
    reReplaceComment = .Replace(S, "$1$2")
End With
End Function
```

### Remove tokens within single quotes

```
('[^']*?)(?:(?:/\*)|(?:\*/))([^']*?')
```

- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nacwC.png) `('[^']*?)`

  - [Match the character “'” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `'`
  - [Match any character that is NOT a “'”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^']*?`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `*?`
- [Match the regular expression below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nacwC.png) `(?:(?:/\*)|(?:\*/))`

  - [Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(?:/\*)`

    - [Match the regular expression below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nacwC.png) `(?:/\*)`

      - [Match the character “/” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `/`
      - [Match the character “*” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\*`
  - [Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(?:\*/)`

    - [Match the regular expression below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nacwC.png) `(?:\*/)`

      - [Match the character “*” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\*`
      - [Match the character “/” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `/`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nacwC.png) `([^']*?')`

  - [Match any character that is NOT a “'”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^']*?`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `*?`
  - [Match the character “'” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `'`

$1$2

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$2`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This expression might help you to replace those undesired `/*`:

```
[A-Z]\s\/\*\s[A-Z]
```

We can simply wrap that in a capturing groups `()`, similar to:

```
([A-Z])\s(\/\*)\s([A-Z])
```

Then, we can replace it with `$1 $3` and ignore the second undesired capturing group:

[image]

[This tool](https://regex101.com/r/P88nyg/1/) helps you to modify/change/edit your expressions, as you wish.

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualize your expressions:

[image]

#### Edit

If you may have more patterns in these capturing groups, you can simply add them using an <kbd>|</kbd>, [such as](https://regex101.com/r/SwOouw/1):

```
([A-Z])\s(\/\*|\*\/)(\s[A-Z]|\x27)
```

You might also want to use `\x27` instead of `'` such that your code would become easy to read.

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /([A-Z])\s(\/\*|\*\/)(\s[A-Z]|\x27)/gm;
const str = `A = 'THIS IS AN ALPHABETIC /* CONSTANT\' || WS_CON1 /* */ || \'TEST STRING */';`;
const subst = `$1$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Performance Test

This snippet returns the runtime of a 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const regex = /([A-Z])\s(\/\*|\*\/)(\s[A-Z]|\x27)/gm;
 const str = `A = 'THIS IS AN ALPHABETIC /* CONSTANT\' || WS_CON1 /* */ || \'TEST STRING */';`;
 const subst = `$1$3`;

 var match = str.replace(regex, subst);
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```